# Android bitmap size reduction not reducing memory

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm new to android and am working on my first real app so i apologize if this question has been answered, or isn't detailed enough. I'm having the common OutOfMemoryError when loading bitmaps to my android app. I've searched around on stackoverflow and went through the google [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) that describes how to use InSampleSize to reduce the memory for each bitmap.

When testing out the app to see how much memory I was saving by down scaling my bitmaps I noticed that the heap size was still growing at the same rate. I.E. When I use an InSampleSize = 8 vs not scaling the bitmap at all (or InSampleSize = 1) the heap grows the same for each.

I have tried printing the byteCount with:
myImage.getByteCount()
for both of the scaling SampleSizes listed above and they both have identical ByteCounts. Is this the expected behavior? Shouldn't the byte count be reduced since I'm downscaling images?
I was expecting to see the memory used to the bitmap reduced by a factor of 8 or so. Am I missing something, or is my understanding of image scaling incorrect? Thanks.

edit: After doing some testing I discovered that if I used createScaledBitmap the memory was reduced but it required me first inflating the original Bitmap then scaling. I'm assuming this is non-ideal since it requires that. I thought the first method would do this for me but according to my heap dumps it isn't.

Initial Code and heap dump:

```
private static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(Resources res, int resId, int width, int height
{
  // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
  final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
  options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

  // Calculate inSampleSize
  options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, height);

  // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
  return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Updated code (same as above with the only difference being) and heap dump:

```
private static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(Resource res, int ResId, int width, int height)
{
  ....
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
  return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, options.outWidth/options.inSampleSize, options.outHeight/options.inSampleSize, false);
}
```

It won't let me post images due to my reputation but according to heap dump it is using 79.155MB. Using the second technique the heap dump is using 26.912 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you scaling the Bitmap after decoding it using `InSampleSize`?

Comment: I don't believe so. I was under the impression that after I created the Bitmap with:  
BitmapFactory.decodeResouce(res, resId, options);  
That the Bitmap would be scaled using the InSampleSize in the options.  
Do I need to scale the Bitmap after via:
bitmap.createdScaledBitmap(bitmap, options.OutHeight/options.InSampleSize, options.OutWidth/options.InSampleSize, false);

Comment: No need but you should try giving `options.inScaled = false;` and `options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;`. This helped me to solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks I'll test it out and let you know.

Comment: After looking at the heap dump I discovered that scaling the bitmap using
bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,     options.OutHeight/options.InSampleSize, options.OutWidth/options.InSampleSize, false);